# Qual a forma correta de fazer um cadastro one to many com DDD

Tags: java, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Tenho estudado DDD e montado uma arquitetura similiar ao livros e exemplos que tenho lido.

Até o momento, quando vou fazer um crud, ao gravar executo algo parecido com isso:

- **UI** : A camada de visualização preenche um objeto com os **dados da tela** ( DTO,ViewModel, command) e chama a camada de interface
- **Interface** : A camada interface (facade) transforma esse objeto com informações da tela em um objeto de **modelo de dominio** e chama a camada de aplicação
- **Aplicação** : A camada de aplicação recebe esse objeto que faz parte da **camada de dominio** e chama um repositorio de infra
- **Infra** : A camada de infra (repositorio) persiste o objeto na base de dados.

**1º pergunta: Essa arquitetura está legal ou escandalosamente errada?**

Asumindo que essa divisão esteja razoavelmente aceitável, a minha dúvida cruel é quanto ao crud de um modelo de dominio que tenha filhos (One to many), exemplo:

Uma tela de cadastro de `Pedido` com vários itens de pedido `PedidoItem` que devem ser cadastrados ao mesmo tempo.

**2ª Pergunta**

Como faço a montagem desse objeto?? 
Eu preencho um viewModel lá em cima na camada de **UI** ( **PedidoViewModel e list** ) e só quando os dados do pedido estiverem todos montados eu mando esse cara pra baixo (camada de aplicação) para ser transformado em um objeto de dominio (**Pedido**) ??

OU

Eu guardo a instância do objeto de dominio (**Pedido**) na camada de aplicação e insiro item a item ( através do **PedidoItemViewModel** ) na mesma camada?

Comment: Apesar da boa intencao de desenvolver orientado a dominio, vc ainda nao conseguiu fugir do BOLOVO. De uma lida nesse artigo, ele explica que [DDD nao e arquitetura em camadas](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2016/08/ddd-nao-e-arquitetura-em-camadas/). Deve te ajudar.

Comment: Ainda tem mta novidade pra mim =( ... mas to tentando me desprender dos conceitos antigos. To atrás de material pra estudar.
Vlw

Comment: Esse projeto, apesar de ser em ASP.NET Core, e um otimo exemplo de otimos patterns como DDD. [Equinox Project](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject).

Comment: Eu escolheria a segunda opção pois a interface não deveria ser sobrecarregada, até por questão de performance. Outra coisa: se quiser falar em DDD, a sua camada "interface" está fazendo o trabalho da camada de Aplicação, e em DDD não existe camada interface e UI pois UI é um tipo de implementação de camada de interface.